# DB2 put multiple values into 1 field

Tags: db2

I have a table like this

```
Store Fruit Color
Abc Apple Red
Abc Apple Green
Abc Grape Black
Abc Grape Red
Abc Grape Green
Def Apple Red
Def Grape Black
Def Grape Green
```

How can I write DB2 SQL that returns me this?

```
Abc Apple Red,Green
Abc Grape Black,Red,Green
Def Apple Red
Def Apple Black,Green
```

Thank you!

I need DB2 SQL that returns:

```
Abc Apple Red,Green
Abc Grape Black,Red,Green
Def Apple Red
Def Apple Black,Green
```

Comment: Search this forum for pivot or pivoting and you will find your answer.

Comment: Look at [LISTAGG](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-listagg) function